# Get Application parameters not working

Tags: node.js, rest, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I use the following lib to be access via code to CF,
https://github.com/prosociallearnEU/cf-nodejs-client

what I need to do is to get app for specific space and get the **app env**

currently **i was able** to get the all apps but not the env for specific app , any idea what I miss here ? I dont get any informative error to be able to understand what can be missed ...

```
const CloudController = new (require("cf-nodejs-client")).CloudController(endpoint, proxy);
    const UsersUAA = new (require("cf-nodejs-client")).UsersUAA;
    const Apps = new (require("cf-nodejs-client")).Apps(endpoint, proxy);
    const Orgs = new (require("cf-nodejs-client")).Organizations(endpoint, proxy);

    CloudController.getInfo()
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            UsersUAA.setEndPoint(result.authorization_endpoint, proxy);
            return UsersUAA.login(username, password);
        }).then((result) => {
        Apps.setToken(result);
         return Apps.getApps();
    }).then((result) => {
        Apps.setToken(result);
        console.log("app guid is: " + result.resources[0].metadata.guid);
        return result.resources[0].metadata.guid;
    }).then((guid) => {
       return Apps.getEnvironmentVariables(guid);
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch((reason) => {
        console.error("Error: " + reason);
    });
```

**UPDATE**

what I need is to get appEnv for specified app (and i've the org & space & App name ), I need that the code will be efficient (performance...) , is my code flow is OK?

Comment: what result do you get when running this command: `cf curl /v2/apps/<guid>/env -X GET`? Make sure you use the same guid returned when you run your node.js app. Also which CF provider are you using? I tested your code with Bluemix and it works fine.

Comment: @AlexdaSilva
Hi Alex, Thanks! currently i've proxy issue to login to my provider...:( , what I need is to get the env for specific app. let's assume that i've the orgName,spaceName,and appName , does my code is OK or I need to change the flow of the code (Im fairly new to CF...), if yes can you please provided it as answer ? thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @AlexdaSilva - I was able to connect to my env and when I run the cf curl /v2/apps/<guid>/env -X GET I was able to get the env data, any idea what it can be missing in the code ?

Comment: I run your code and it works fine for me (I did not use proxy), so I guess there could be some issues with your proxy, but I cannot tell for sure. Did you use the same guid from your application in the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your request (get app environment) and the documentation here: [cf-nodejs-client v0.13 documentation](https://prosociallearneu.github.io/cf-nodejs-client/docs/v0.13.0/Apps.html), it appears that the getEnvirnmentVariables function would give you what you need.

As an alternative, you could do the following:

```
var cfenv = require('cfenv');
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();
```